# Highcharts: what is the difference between event.target and event.currentTarget

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highcharts.

I have the following for a column chart:

```
xAxis: {
....
  events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function(event) {

        //do some work here. 
        //event has a property called target
        //event has another property called currentTarget
    }
  }
...
}
```

I notice that event has two properties that seem to be identical (I am not sure). Are they the same? Any differnce? I need to know the final x values shown on a chart after zooming.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery, it would be the same as those in jQuery events

> ```
> event.currentTarget                                 Returns: Element
>
> Description: The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.
> ```

Read More @ http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/

> ```
> event.target                                        Returns: Element
>
> Description: The DOM element that initiated the event.
> ```

Read More @ http://api.jquery.com/event.target/